# Devise Username with spaces login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have the following devise model (edited for brevity)

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :token_authenticatable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable,
         :authentication_keys => [:login], :reset_password_keys => [ :login ]

  attr_accessor :login
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :login

  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates :email, :presence => true
  validates_uniqueness_of    :email,     :case_sensitive => false, :allow_blank => true, :if => :email_changed?, :scope => :id
  validates_format_of :email, :with  => Devise.email_regexp, :allow_blank => true, :if => :email_changed?
  validates_presence_of   :password, :on=>:create
  validates_confirmation_of   :password, :on=>:create
  validates_length_of :password, :within => Devise.password_length, :allow_blank => true

  def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions).where(["name = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
    else
      where(conditions).first
    end
  end

  def email_required?
    false
  end

  def email_changed?
    false
  end

end
```

And I have followed the guide on [this link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address) to enable signin with either name or email.

Here's the problem:

Students with names > 2 words cant sign in, e.g. "Adam Bravo Charlie"

Single names e.g "Adam" or names with <= 2 words e.g "Adam Bravo" can be signed in.

The school requires students to use their full names with accompanying spaces to login. How do I enable my students to sign in with their full names and whitespaces?

Comment: I havn't dig the code but using user name instead of full name with space is the convention all over the web. Think about Google, Facebook, Twitter, StackOverflow. Follow the convention.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, however I'm trying to modify a legacy app. The students use their full names as opposed to usernames due to the school's requirements. If it proves impossible, then I'll change the app to follow conventions. Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok turns out the solution is simpler than i thought.

**config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :name]
config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :name ]
```

and voila, login with full name is now possible!

Answer (score 3):

On the login form, I would take a string and convert it to a slug. Authenticate with the slug as the `username`. When creating a new user, use the `before_create` method and `parameterize` the full name. This would allow you to have an unlimited number of spaces, including punctuation characters (periods and commas). This would give the feel of the user entering their full name as their username when in turn, it's going to `parameterize` the user's full name and use this as the username to login.

Comment: Sounds logical, and implementable. How do I deal with existing users though?